# For loop not working due to string array

Tags: php, string, file

I'm having a serious problem where my code is not entering the for loop. I am using the for loop on what should be a string array of `$arrayitems`. I believe I'm using the file function correctly to load that but the program never enters the for loop.

```
$arrayxitems = file("/home/web/sites/www.riders.com/gapi/feeds/productlistnew.txt");

$itemlist=array();
$x=0;

foreach($arrayxitems as $arrayx){

}
```

Comment: is there any errors ? and you have nothing in the loop ?

Comment: "What should be a string of array..." Did you do a var dump of what it contains?

Comment: The only reason the `foreach` loop wouldn't be entered is if the file is empty or you don't have permission to read it.

Comment: `var_dump($arrayxitems)` will show you what you're working with. if that file's not readable or the path is wrong, you'll end up with a boolean false which can't be foreach'd anyways.

Comment: I don't get why people come here before even checking what they are trying to foreach on, basic debugging skills people.

Comment: i suggest you try to open a file in the same directory with the script,. see if it works,. make sure the file is NOT empty with some lines of string inside,.

Comment: @DanyCaissy You're relatively new here, aren't you? Get used to the fact that there are lots of programmers out there who don't know how to program, let alone how to debug, and they use SO as a substitute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can verity if the file open works with the if statement (since [file](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php) returns false upon failure):

```
$arrayxitems = file("/home/web/sites/www.riders.com/gapi/feeds/productlistnew.txt");
if (! $arrayxitems) {
    // you have an error, so do something about it.

}
$itemlist=array();
$x=0;

foreach($arrayxitems as $arrayx){

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You were absolutely right Barmar. It was a problem with file permissions. var_dump and i get bool false.